# CSS media query's issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net, media-queries, screen-resolution

I am trying to get the right points of my application that brakes so i can add a media query to my application. I found a great website called http://responsivepx.com/ to test my application out on.

I ran my application and seen that it shows my application brakeing between 1257 width and 1576 width and then after that my application will be fine again. So i edit my query to fill the needs of the resolution issue and still it is not working?

Here is the querys i have at the moment:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/CommonStyle/Common1600Style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/CommonStyle/Common1280Style.css" />
```

And then i added this to the media querys and it still doesnt work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1258px) and (max-width: 1576px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css" />
```

Does anyone know the reason my application is breaking and not hitting that media query?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'not hitting that media query'? I'm a bit in the dark here because you haven't given an example css rule which isn't applied or provided the contents of any of the stylesheets, or even stated what your window size is when you see a problem. But here goes.

Are you sure it's not a rule precedence issue? If your browser window is between 1257px and 1280px then there will be two sets of rules the browser is trying to apply e.g. both stylesheets `Common1280Style.css` and `MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css` are loaded and a more specific rule in `Common1280Style.css` will still override one in `MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css`.

This assumes you are loading the stylesheets in the order shown e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1600px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/CommonStyle/Common1600Style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1280px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/CommonStyle/Common1280Style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1258px) and (max-width: 1576px)" type="text/css" href="../Style/MaxWidth1280StyleSheet.css" />
```

To illustrate what I mean, here's a http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bjwsa notice the color rule for (max-width: 1280) takes precedence over the one for (min-width: 1258px) and (max-width: 1576px) if the browser width is between 1258px and 1280px . Because its more specific e.g. a rule for `body #example` is considered more specific than just `#example`